# Continuous delivery is disabled in azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Currently I am working with CI/CD of azure function using VSTS. In this I am able to deploy my code successfully. After deployment it was showing that "Your app is setup to use Continuous Delivery with VSTS.  Click on the 'Continuous Delivery' item on the left menu to configure it"in the azure portal. But, continuous delivery is disabled here. What should I do to enable it. Could any one suggest.

Comment: Please the related thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff282236-e296-48c9-8eb0-4db53b8001c0/disabling-vsts-continuous-delivery-for-azure-function-app?forum=AzureFunctions).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Go to https://resources.azure.com/
2. Find your function app by searching or in the tree, under your resource group -> providers -> Microsoft.Web -> sites
3. Under it, open Config / Web
4. Click Edit (may need to set it to read/write first)
5. In the JSON, change scmType to None
6. Click PUT

Then go back to Portal and try again.